# Wiring ClientRegistrationService with jdbc datasource

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

I could successfully set the jdbc datasource to Spring OAuth2 using the following configuration. However I am struggling to wire `ClientRegistrationService` while it was easy to wire `ClientDetailsService`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }
    .....
}
```

Here is what I tried

1. Below code fails to find the `ClientDetailsService` is not `instanceof` or of `assignableFrom` `JdbcClientDetailsService` or `ClientRegistrationService`

   @Controller
   public class ClientPortalApplication {

   ```
   private ClientRegistrationService clientService;

   @Autowired
   public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
       if (clientDetailsService instanceof JdbcClientDetailsService)) {
           clientService = (ClientRegistrationService) clientDetailsService;
       }
   }
   ......
   ```

   }
2. Below code wiring fails on finding a bean of type `ClientRegistrationService`

:

```
@Controller
public class ClientPortalApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationService clientService;

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientDetailsService` created in yout `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`  is not a bean therefore can't be injected. A solution is to create a bean `JdbcClientDetailsService` inject it in the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and you will be able to inject it anywhere else:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
    public JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService;
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(jdbcClientDetailsService);
        }
    }    
}
```